# Keep bins between 5% and 95% of a histogram in OpenCV/Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am intending to skip some histograms of an image in the extreme points of the distribution of any gray image.
The extreme points to the left are represented by all the histograms lying in the region of 5%, and to the right are represented by all histograms in a region above 95% of the whole distribution
Here are some codes to where I ended

```
image = cv2.imread('right.'+str(i)+'.png')
#print(image)
hist = cv2.calcHist([image], [0], None, [256], [0,256])
lower = round(0.05*len(hist))
upper = round(0.95*len(hist))
lower_hist_list = hist[0:lower]
upper_hist_list = hist[upper:len(hist)]
lower_hist, upper_hist
remaining_region =hist[index_above_lower : index_before_upper]
```

what I want is the histograms between the lower and upper boundaries `5%<=IMAGE<=95%?`

Comment: In what way do you mean "skip".  Bins are always there unless you reprocess the image to clip the data. Or you can just not print those bins, I suppose.

Comment: As I have shown in the last line, I want to have an image whose histograms lie between the region (above 5% and below 95%). that means I don't want the histograms from 96% and above or from 1 to 4% l(less than 5%).

Comment: Let's assume you have a low contrast image where the darkest pixel is 80 and the brightest is 120. Now 5% of the pixels are under 85 and 95% of the pixels are under 110. So, 1) do you want to change the brightness of the image? 2) do you want to increase the contrast so that pixel brightness 85 gets mapped to 0 and pixel brightness 110 gets mapped to 255? Or something else? Thank you.

Comment: You can use skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity() to map input values to output values and thus stretch the input values from x1>0 to x2<255 to fill the ouput range (0 to 255).

Comment: @KimwagaMakono Do you mean something like MATLAB `imadjust` with [stretchlim](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/stretchlim.html)? Or, do you mean finding the lower and upper percentile of the image using the histogram - computing [numpy.percentile](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html) using a given histogram? Or do you mean the interpretation of the answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my understanding of your question; you would like to avoid pixel intensities that are on the tail ends of your histogram. Pixels below 5% and above 95% of the distribution must be clipped.

First, obtain histogram of your grayscale image with 256 bins:

```
hist = cv2.calcHist([img],[0],None,[256],[0,256])
```

[image]

`hist` stores the number of pixels having values each between [0 - 255].

- 5% of 256 ~ 12
- 95% of 256 ~ 243

Based on your criteria, we need to keep pixel values in the range [12 - 243]. We can use [`np.clip()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) for this purpose:

```
img2 = np.clip(img, 12, 243)
plt.hist(img2.ravel(),256,[0,256])
```

[image]

Looking at the plot above:

- pixel values below 12 have been assigned the value 12
- pixel values above 243 have been assigned the value 243

Hence you can see the spike at both these values in the plot.

Comment: Nice answer. My interpretation of the question was miles away‍♂️